# Sorting NSMutableArray that contains NSMutableDictionary by the dictionary key's value

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSMutableArray` with 70 objects, they are `NSMutableDictionary`, inside each dictionary I have 2 values: "distance" and "indexPath". I want to sort the `NSMutableArray` from the small distance to the biggest. The distance is in KM and the array looks like this after using the code that I pasted here:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[branchDistance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

This is the result of this method:

```
(lldb) po [branchDistance objectAtIndex:0]
(id) $1 = 0x0d6ac240 {
    "<NSIndexPath 0xd6cf180> 1 indexes [0]" = indexPath;
    "8.078547" = distance;
}
(lldb) po [branchDistance objectAtIndex:1]
(id) $2 = 0x0d6a64a0 {
    "<NSIndexPath 0xd6cf3b0> 1 indexes [1]" = indexPath;
    "45.044069" = distance;
}
(lldb) po [bran(lldb) po [branchDistance objectAtIndex:2]
(id) $4 = 0x0d6cf550 {
    "<NSIndexPath 0xd69b3f0> 1 indexes [2]" = indexPath;
    "9.992081" = distance;
}
(lldb) po [branchDistance objectAtIndex:3]
(id) $5 = 0x0d6cf750 {
    "283.356727" = distance;
    "<NSIndexPath 0xd6cf480> 1 indexes [3]" = indexPath;
}
```

I want to sort the `NSMutableArray` from the small number to the big number, using this "distance" key value inside the `NSMutableDictionary`. I tried few pieces of code from the web and from stackoverflow, but couldn't find something that worked for me.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the distance values are stored in the dictionaries using an `NSNumber` object:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [branchDistance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *distance1 = [(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectForKey:@"distance"];
    NSNumber *distance2 = [(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectForKey:@"distance"];
    return [distance1 compare:distance2];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't working, the `sortedArray` is still the same as the branchDistance.

Comment: @YossiTsafar Please confirm how distance is stored.  Is it using `NSNumber` or using `NSString`?  If the latter then use the former as that is easier to use.

Comment: tell me please, if I want to sort it using "name" instead of distance? meaning chars instead of number. How should I do that?

Comment: @YossiTsafar You can use roughly the same code, except that `NSString` provides the `compare:` and `caseInsensitiveCompare:` methods meaning you don't need the `if (x < y) ...` statements.  If you want a more complete answer then ask another SO question and I'll provide the complete code fragment (it's off topic for this question).

Comment: let me try on my own, if I will not succeed I will ask another question. thank you.

Comment: @YossiTsafar Actually this "chat" prompted me to look for a `compare:` method in the `NSNumber` class and there is one.  I have updated my answer and your question about `NSString` will be very similar.